# Mechanism of a manual Crank Adjustable Height Standing Desk

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hydraulics, mechanisms, actuator

I am trying to figure out the lifting mechanism of a manual Crank Adjustable Height Standing Desk. Please see the image below:

[image]

My question is what it is inside the metal frame (check the red marked area)
that is causing the entire system go up and down when I move the crank?

Comment: I think the lead screw mechanism is used inside the bases. If you have made a table so far, thank you for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the crank handle is connected to the little black box, inside of which there are gears that rotate the metal shaft you can see running through the box and across the back of the table support. the right hand end of that shaft enters the support leg on the right which has another gearbox in it that rotates a shaft leading down the length of the support leg. That shaft has threads cut into it which engage a nut fixed to the lower portion of the support leg. rotating the crank handle then rotates the threaded shaft inside the leg which causes that shaft to push up or pull down on the upper half half of the support leg via the bearings inside the gearbox that is inside the top of the leg. This raises or lowers the table.

Comment: Good answer, better with a diagram ;)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Why don't you go ahead and make one, then? ...